# Gradle. How to print all files from collect{}

Tags: java, gradle

From [Gradle tutorial: part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7alCuE7cNVQ), how to print files through zipTree iteration, on each step?

```
from configurations.compile.collect{zipTree(it)}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for:

```
from configurations.compile.collect {
   println it
   zipTree(it)
}
```

?

Comment: Could you explain why       from configurations.compile.collect {
   println it
   zipTree(it)
}       works but NOT       from configurations.compile.collect {
   zipTree(it)
   println it
}

Comment: Yes, from in groovy the last statement of a method/closure is returned. `println` returns nothing (`void`), if you change the order, nothing will be returned, hence the method fails. If the problem is solved, please accept it.